# MySQL string manipulation to count values in a field

Tags: mysql, string, count

I have this string manipulation

```
select product,
       CAST((LENGTH(currencies) - LENGTH(REPLACE(currencies, '*', ''))) / LENGTH('*') AS UNSIGNED) AS currencies_count
  from MY_TABLE
```

to count "currencies" in a single field in this table

```
product       currencies
-----------   --------------
prod_name_1   *usd*cad*euro*
prod_name_2   *usd*cad*
prod_name_3   *usd*cad*euro*
prod_name_4   
prod_name_5   *usd*
```

The string manipulation returns a "+1" on all results (for exaple: prod_name_1, 4 currencies instead of 3). This because an external component store checkboxes data in this non-coherent manner (*usd*cad*euro* instead of *usd*cad*euro).

The point is that I can't change the storage method of this component. There is a way to count the exact number of currencies in a field, ignoring the last "blank" value after the last '*' separator?
How can I modify my string manipulation?

Getting crazy, any help will be very, very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query above is not counting the empty part of the string after the final *. It's not even splitting it at all. It's simply saying that:

```
*eur*usd*
```

is 3 characters longer than

```
eurusd
```

To get the correct value I think you should just check for an empty currencies value, and if found then set the result to 0. Otherwise the result is the number of * symbols minus 1:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(Currencies) = 0 THEN CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) 
        ELSE CAST((LENGTH(Currencies) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Currencies, '*', ''))) / LENGTH('*') AS UNSIGNED) - 1 END AS currencies_count
FROM MY_TABLE
```

I don't have a mysql database to to test that against but it should be OK.

Comment: ,@Splugged:Since we know that all data is +1-ed, can't we just subtract 1 ???

select product,
       CAST((LENGTH(currencies) - LENGTH(REPLACE(currencies, '*', '')))-1 / LENGTH('*') AS UNSIGNED) AS currencies_count
  from MY_TABLE

Comment: Hi Tobsey, hi gentrobot. Both true! It works! Thanks! Many thanks!

Comment: @Splugged what about cases without currencies and asterisks at all? Than you'll get `-1` - am I right? and `SELECT CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED)` -> 18446744073709551615.

Comment: @Splugged be careful with gentrobot's query. It assumes that `LENGTH('*') = 1`which is not necessarily true. The LENGTH() function returns the data length in bytes, not chars. @Michal - your answer may be more correct if they are NULLs in the empty fields. I assumed they were empty varchar fields, '', but it depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just substract 1 from calculated value, if it's greater than 0.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountCurrencies(s VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(3)) 
RETURNS INT 
BEGIN 
  SET @n = (LENGTH(s) - LENGTH(REPLACE(s, delim, ''))) / LENGTH(delim);
  IF @n > 0 THEN 
    RETURN @n - 1; 
  ELSE 
    RETURN 0; 
END IF; 
END


SELECT product, CountCurrencies(currencies, '*') FROM my_table;
```

But it's the ugly way, manipulate data inside the column. You should decompose it.